# How fetch first element from json list in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have following list of ids in json format. I want to access first id in selenium using java. I tried using

```
String item = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[1]")).getText();
```

but didn't help.

```
 <body>
   <div id="json">
       <span class="collapser"></span>
         {
            <ul class="obj collapsible">
               <li>
                 <span class="prop" title="<root>.hdps">
                   <span class="q">"</span>
                  hdps
                   <span class="q">"</span>
                 </span>
                :
                <span class="collapser"></span>
                 [
                    <ul class="array collapsible">
                          <li>
                              <span class="num">65085</span>
                                  ,
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <span class="num">65089</span>
                                   ,
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <span class="num">65711</span>
                                   ,
                          </li>

                      </ul>
                      ]
               </li>
     </ul>
 }
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by didn't help??  explain more...

Comment: I am using an API which gives me list of ids in json which looks like: {

    "hdps": [
        65085,
        65089,
        65711,
        66218,
        69773
    ]

} I am seeing an exception for locator.no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul//li[1]"}

Comment: Id's list means some thing like this :- `[65085,65089,65711]`..??

Comment: Why are you using selenium to parse a json response from an api call?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes, it is a list of numbers and I want to copy first element.

Comment: As you provided the HTML..is it present on page with JSON format or anything else??? please explain.. why are you using selenium here??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I am writing a case where I need an unique id to see the details of the property . The API that I am using gives list of property ids. I want any id from the list, preferably first, to append to the home URL and navigate to details page.

Comment: Try once with this:- `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.num:nth-child(1)")).getText(); ` and let me know..

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Comment: Paste it your browser console `document.querySelector("span.num:nth-child(1)")` at details page and let me know what it returns ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand is you are trying to read the value of ID attribute of an element. I am really not sure the intent of your question . But this how you can get to the value of ID.

- You will need to get reference to the element using one of the various element locators. In this case, you have leveraged `By.xpath()`. You can validate the correctness of the `XPATH` used by Firefox `Xpath` checker. Once you use correct `XPATH` , you will get reference of `webElement`.

  ```
  WebElement wElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[1]"));
  // validate the correct XPATH using available tools - ex : firefox xpath checker etc.
  ```
- You will need to get the value of `id` attribute of the element.

  ```
  String requiredID = wElement.getAttribute("id");
  ```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

As **pendem** answered that, you can get first ID as you want by using xpath. But here I found that the xpath which you have used find 2 elements as there are two **ul** elements having **li**. If you use xpath having specific ul with class attribute as - **.//ul[@ class="array collapsible"]//li[1]** will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided all the relevant HTML, it should be as simple as the below.

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.num")).getText();
```

This just returns the first instance of the IDs.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to do some more digging, e.g. is this in an IFRAME or is it a timing issue or ?